# Scala - methods with functions as arguments

Tags: scala

Trying to get my head around using functions as arguments to methods.  For a simple example let's use:

```
case class IntegrationOption(id: Option[Long], name: String, iconUrl: String)

val availableOptions = List(
   IntegrationOption(Some(1), "blah1", "dsaadsf.png"),
   IntegrationOption(Some(2), "blah2", "dsaadsf.png")
)
```

I want to pass in a function to something like this:

```
def getIntegrationOption(ARG) = {
  availableOptions.find(ARG)
}
```

where ARG might be:

```
x => x.id == Option(id)
```

or

```
x => x.name == "blah1"
```

Ideas?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
def getIntegrationOption(predicate: IntegrationOption => Boolean) = 
  availableOptions.find(predicate)
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
getIntegrationOption(_.iconUrl == "dsaadsf.png")
```

Note that since `IntegrationOption` is already a case class, you can do some fancier searching with pattern matching and partially applied functions:

```
availableOptions.collectFirst{
  case IntegrationOption(Some(1), name, _) => name
}
```

or:

```
availableOptions.collectFirst{
  case io@IntegrationOption(_, "blah2", _) => io
}
```

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is declare a parameter that's a function, then you can use the parameter like any other function or pass it to higher-order functions like `find`:

```
def getIntegrationOption(f: IntegrationOption => Boolean) = {
  availableOptions.find(f)
}
getIntegrationOptions(x => x.name == "blah1")
//or you could do just
getIntegrationOptions(_.name == "blah1")
```